# Sort inside a formating node

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I need to display the XML with the total sum of the distance of the day sorted so that the day with most kilometers is shown first
I was able only to make the sum of the distance

**Input**

```
<output>
    <cars>
        <car>
          <id>1</id>
          <license>B-01-TST</license>
        </car>
        <car>
          <id>2</id>
          <license>IF-02-TST</license>
        </car>
    </cars>
    <distances>
        <distance>
          <id_car>1</id_car>
          <date>20110901</date>
          <distance>111</distance>
        </distance>     
        <distance>
          <id_car>1</id_car>
          <date>20110903</date>
          <distance>56</distance>
        </distance>
        <distance>
          <id_car>2</id_car>
          <date>20110901</date>
          <distance>92</distance>
        </distance>
        <distance>
          <id_car>2</id_car>
          <date>20110902</date>
          <distance>97</distance>
        </distance>
    </distances>
</output>
```

**Output expected**

```
<output>
<cars>
    <car>
        <id>1</id>
        <license>B-01-TST</license>
        <distance totalKm="Day 01: 111"/>
        <distance totalKm="Day 03: 56"/>
    </car>
    <car>
        <id>2</id>
        <license>IF-02-TST</license>
        <distance totalKm="Day 01: 92"/>
        <distance totalKm="Day 02: 97"/>
    </car>
</cars>
```

I'm not able to copy all the XSL because its too much code for the question,
so the main info about is this

**So far the XSL looks like this:**

```
<xsl:key name="byCarIdAndDate" match="distance" use="concat(id_car, '|', date)"/>
<xsl:key name="byCarId" match="distance" use="id_car"/>
<xsl:template match="car">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('byCarId', id)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="distance[generate-id()= generate-id(key('byCarIdAndDate', concat(id_car, '|', date))[1])]">
    <xsl:variable name="thisDate" select="key('byCarIdAndDate', concat(id_car, '|', date))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="sum" select="sum($thisDate/distance)"/>
    <!--make some sort by higher value -->
    <distance totalKm="Day {substring(date, 7, 2)}: {$sum}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

to remove the distance block I'm doing like this *template match="distances| distance"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to resort to `xsl:for-each-group` then to group by date and to allow us to easily sum a group:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="byCarId" match="distances/distance" use="id_car"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="distances"/>

    <xsl:template match="car">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="key('byCarId', id)" group-by="date">
                <xsl:sort select="sum(current-group()/distance)" order="descending"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="distance">
        <distance totalKm="Day {substring(date, 7, 2)}: {sum(current-group()/distance)}"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/3MvmrAX

Comment: Thanks man! Could you please explain to me how does this for-each-group works? I'm assuming that as it is inside the template car it is considering everithing inside the tags `<car></car>` as a group and applying the function for-each in a massive form, is that it ?

Comment: Please understand that XSLT 2 is a publically accessible standard, so refer to https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping for details on how grouping works. In the posted snippet the grouping population is selected through the expression `key('byCarId', id)` which references the `distances/distance` elements related by the `id` value of the `car`.

Comment: You might also want to look at books like https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm which treat the language with a focus on practical use if the spec is too technical.